# How to check that the columns exist with expected data types in a csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to validate the data in the csv file before loading to the data base table. The column names with their expected data types must be checked before loading. I tried with ASSERT but fails. As an example I have the below snippet intended to do the check but it errors out -

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age']) 
assert df.dtypes.to_dict() == {"Name": str, "Age":int} -- here it gives Assertion error even though the column format is as expected
```

**Error**
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[28], line 1
> ----> 1 assert df.dtypes.to_dict() == {"Name": str, "Age":int}
>
> AssertionError: *

Comment: Have you checked the output of `df.dtypes.to_dict()`? You have object and int64, what exactly are the rules?

Comment: I am new to Python and not sure if that was the right way. Without to_Dict it errors out -
assert df.dtypes == {"Name": str, "Age":int}

Comment: The issue is that `object != str` and `int != Int64`

Comment: I have tried using object and Int64 but gives syntax error

Comment: It is actually more difficult than you think. Add the following lines before the assert:


`print(df.dtypes)`


`print(df.dtypes.to_dict())`
This will show what pandas is producing, but I have been unable to get 'assert' to recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're comparing different dtypes.

```
# df.dtypes
Name    object
Age      int64
dtype: object
```

So the correct comparison should be:

```
df.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict() == {'Name': 'object', 'Age': 'int64'}
# True
```

Or:

```
import numpy as np

df.dtypes.to_dict() == {'Name': np.dtype('O'), 'Age': np.dtype('int64')}
# True
```

Note that a more robust option would be to use [`is_string_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_string_dtype.html)/[`is_integer_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_integer_dtype.html):

```
assert (pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df['Name']) and
        pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df['Age'])
       )
```

Comment: I tried the first and it works. But if you could explain how it works that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DibyaMishra `df.dtypes` return type/dtype objects, in the first code we convert to string to perform an easy comparison. In the second code we use the actual dtype objects

Answer (score 0):

A string column in Pandas is going to appear as data type `object`.

Using your example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

print(df.dtypes)
```

The output is:

```
df.dtypes
Name    object
Age      int64
dtype: object
```

Since you are loading this into a database table, I would assume you are using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` function. The option `dtype` in that function is going to be your friend for validation.

From the pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.2.1/pandas/core/generic.py#L2870-L3095):

> Specify the dtype (especially useful for integers with missing values).
> Notice that while pandas is forced to store the data as floating point,
> the database supports nullable integers. When fetching the data with
> Python, we get back integer scalars.

```
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, None, 2]})
    >>> df
         A
    0  1.0
    1  NaN
    2  2.0

    >>> from sqlalchemy.types import Integer
    >>> df.to_sql(name='integers', con=engine, index=False,
    ...           dtype={"A": Integer()})
    3

    >>> with engine.connect() as conn:
    ...   conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM integers")).fetchall()
    [(1,), (None,), (2,)]
```